# Twilio caller-id verification call : voice customization

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-click-to-call

I was going through https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/outgoing-caller-ids. I have no issues in adding a new caller-id, and all the callbacks are working fine.

I want to be able to customize the voice call we receive to enter the code. This customization could be changing the voice or even changing the text that the agent speaks. The documentation doesn't have anything on this. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot customize the voice or the message for Verified CallerID.